# How to store the value on ng-repeat input on one single click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project wer I need to store the values of ng-repeat Input values as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

1) I need to push QuestionId which I will get in one API.
2) Need to push AnswerId Which is related to the QuestionId.

Somethig like this:

```
$scope.items({
            QuestionId: $scope.questionId,
            AnswerId: $scope.answerId
        },{
            QuestionId: $scope.questionId,
            AnswerId: $scope.answerId
        }
);
```

Below is the ng-repeat:

[image: ng-repeat]

The click button is at the bottom which I cudnt capture in screenshot.
Can anyone let me know how I can achive this.

Comment: what does your `ng-repeat` actually look like? and where is the click supposed to happen?

Comment: That screenshot looks like a lazy's work. It is always helpful if you explain in detail with minimal information required.

Comment: please don't provide a screenshot of code.  Instead, provide a [mcve] of your issue, so others can actually work with your code.